# How do I use tsc-watch (or similar) to watch for changes to all files, recompile, and copy them into my build/dist folder?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

Right now I have a package.json scripts section that looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "views": "cp -r ./src/views/ ./dist/views/",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"./run.sh\"",
    "prod": "./run.sh",
    "test": "jest --coverage --verbose"
}
```

Inside run.sh I have:

```sh
npm run views && node ./dist/server.js
```

When I run `npm run dev` I expect it to compile `.ts` files within `./src/` to `.js` files within `./dist/` then copy everything (`.html`) within `./src/views/` to `./dist/views/` then wait for any changes to `.ts` files, once a `.ts` file change occurs tsc-watch would rerun the process.

However, `tsc-watch` somehow detects changes when `cp -r ./src/views/ ./dist/views/` is run, despite it not changing any `.ts` files. This results in an infinite loop when running `npm run dev` where it compiles the `.ts` to `.js` then copies views, detects changes, and loops forever.

It appears a request for exactly what I'm trying to do was requested but shot down for some reason [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835).

So, with or without tsc-watch, how do I...

1. Watch for changes to any and all files.
2. When a change occurs, copy all files from `src` to `dist`, compiling any `.ts` to `.js`.
3. Do so with as little overhead as possible and without any infinite loops.